# Target the preceding element form my selector

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I want to scrape all `<li>` from multiple `<ul>` on a page using scrapy, I have a for loop that grabs all `<li>`s inside the current `<ul>`, what I would like to do is grab the text from the `<p>` that is just before the current `ul`, I assume using preceding-sibling is the way to go but I can not get it to work, any suggestions?

```
<p>some random text</p>
<ul>
    <li> some random text </li>
    <li> some random text </li>
    <li> some random text </li>
    <li> some random text </li>
    <li> some random text </li>
</ul>

<p>some random text</p>
<ul>
    <li> some random text </li>
    <li> some random text </li>
    <li> some random text </li>
    <li> some random text </li>
    <li> some random text </li>
</ul>
```

my for loop is:

```
for lis in response.xpath('//div[@id="tabname-2228-2"]/ul'):
```

I have tried:

```
for lis in response.xpath('//div[@id="tabname-2228-2"]/ul'):season = 
  lis.xpath('preceding::p/text()').extract()
```

Comment: To me, the relationship between your XPath expressions and your XML is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `preceding-sibling::p` not `preceeding`.

```
lis.xpath('preceding-sibling::p[1]/text()').extract()
```

Complete solution:

```
for lis in response.xpath('//div[@id="tabname-2228-2"]/ul'):
    season = lis.xpath('preceding::p[1]/text()')[0]
    print(season)
```

Comment: Tiny suggestion of typo fixing: `.//preceding-sibling::p/text()`.

Comment: To add to that OP should probably select just first preceding-sibling rather than _all_ of them: `preceding-sibling::p[1]`

Comment: @vezunchik we don't have to specify `.//` when working with scrapy.

Comment: I have tried variations of all of these and still return nothing                                                                                
 for items in response.xpath('//div[@id="2228-2"]/ul'):
                item = items.xpath(
                    'preceding-sibling::p[1]/text()').extract()
                print('Item: %s ' % (item))

Comment: @supputuri no I am not

Comment: check the updated answer under complete solution.

Comment: And are you sure the `ul` is child of `//div[@id="tabname-2228-2"]`?

Comment: Tried the updated code and it returns an error: IndexError: list index out of range, yes I am sure the the ul is a child of the div, inside the dive the pattern is p ul p ul p ul ...

Comment: Is it failing at `season` line or `for lis` line?

Comment: the error is on this line: season = lis.xpath('preceding::p[1]/text()')[0]

Comment: Have you tried without index at the end. `season = lis.xpath('preceding::p[1]/text()')`

Comment: Yes I tried various versions without finding one that returns a value, all I get is an empty variable

Comment: hmm, one more try. This should return the element  `season = lis.xpath('preceding-sibling::p[1]')`

Comment: bingo, this is correct now, thank you so much for the help

Comment: Cool, Please edit the answer, with working code (if there is any change).